# Routing controllers in sub folders - Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have admin folder in my controllers Folder.
Structure as Below.

- Controllers
  ----admin

  -----------Admin.php

  -----------Dashboard.php

How to set a default controller?

I am getting 404 Page Not Found

```
http://localhost:8080/project/admin/
$routes['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am maintaining my admin related controller's in a directory (Controllers/admin/)

//ADMIN

```
//$route['folder'] = "folder/home";
$route['admin'] = 'admin/admin';

$route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['admin/logout'] = 'admin/profile';
$route['admin/home'] = 'admin/home';
```

Comment: Please don't simply post a sample of code, but try to explain in which way it answers the question and how it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
$route['folder'] = "folder/home";
$route['admin'] = 'admin/admin';

$route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['admin/logout'] = 'admin/profile';
$route['admin/home'] = 'admin/home';
```

Comment: Please don't simply post a sample of code, but try to explain in which way it answers the question and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in CodeIgniter 3

[Reference >>>](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#directories-and-default-controller-404-override)